# Keyword super evaluates to nil inside a Rails model initialization. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, which inherits from ActiveRecord::Base

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Irrelevant code ...
    def initialize(*a)
        super.initialize(*a)
        @myattr = {}
    end
    # Irrelevant code ...
end
```

When MyModel.new is called (actually, I call `someobj.my_models.new` since my_models is a 1:N relation to MyModel), `initialize` is called in the context of the newly created instance, but `super` evaluates to `nil` (`self` is an instance of `MyModel` but `super` evaluates to `nil`).

Naturally, a line like `super.initialize(*a)` explodes with the expected error given the situation: `private method`initialize' called for nil:NilClass`

Why could this be happening?

ruby: 2.2.2
rails: 4.2.0

Comment: Unrelated, but you can just say `super` IIRC. Also unrelated, but overriding `initialize` used to be frowned upon, and I'm not sure why you'd need it given `after_initialize`.

Comment: Just guessing: `super` looks for a method in the parent class with the same name. [ActiveRecord::Base](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b0994d07c4ddda5e8b5317db56ef4e7c20e4c9ea/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb)'s `initialize` method returns nil. So in effect you're calling `nil.initialize(*a)`, which explains the error.

Comment: @BroiSatse true. I updated the comment, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super` is a keyword which invokes the superclass's definition of the current method; since the superclass's definition of `initialize` returns nil, you get the error you're seeing.

However, I'm assuming what you actually wanted to do is just invoke that method with the given arguments, which you can accomplish with just:

```
def initialize(*a)
  super(*a)
  # etc
end
```

Comment: As a side note, I think you may have been thinking that `super` is a reference to the superclass itself. It's not (if you want that, `self.class.superclass` will get you it); it's instead a special keyword that actually performs a method call with the arguments given to it.

Comment: I'm sorry. Came from Python 3 background.